# How to preg_split without losing a character?

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this

```
$string = "Hello; how are you;Hey, I am fine";
$new = preg_split("/;\w/", $string);
print_r($new);
```

I am trying to split the string only when there is no white-space between the words and ";". But when I do this, I lose the H from Hey. It's probably because the split happens through the recognition of ;H. Could someone tell me how to prevent this?

My output:

```
$array  =   [
  0 => [
    0 => 'Hello; how are you ',
    1 => 0,
  ],
  1 => [
    0 => 'ey, I am fine',
    1 => 21,
  ],
]
```

Comment: Use a [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for the letter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b`:

[`\b;\b`](https://regex101.com/r/wmEWQP/1/)

```
$string = "Hello; how are you;Hey, I am fine";
$new = preg_split("/\b;\b/", $string);
print_r($new);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/giKaH)

Or a negative [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and negative lookbehind

[`(?<! );(?! )`](https://regex101.com/r/wmEWQP/2/)

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/kuXif)

Answer (score 1):

Lookarounds cost more steps. In terms of pattern efficiency, a word boundary is better and maintains the intended "no-length" character consumption.

In well-formed English, you won't ever have to check for a space before a semi-colon, so only 1 word boundary seems sufficient (I don't know if malformed English is possible because it is not represented in your sample string).

If you want to acquire the offset value, `preg_split()` has a flag for that.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/QS6Bk))

```
$string = "Hello; how are you;Hey, I am fine";
$new = preg_split("/;\b/", $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
var_export($new);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Hello; how are you',
    1 => 0,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Hey, I am fine',
    1 => 19,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are capturingthe `\w` in your regex.You dont want that. Therefore, do this:

```
$new = preg_split("/;(?=\w)/", $string);
```

A capture group is defined in brackets, but the ?= means match but don't capture.

Check it out here https://3v4l.org/Q77LZ

Comment: I think you didn't read the question properly. OP wants to split the string **only** when there is **no** white-space between the words and ";"

Answer (score 0):

Use split with this regex `;(?=\w)` then you will not lose the *H*